# Coloring PyQt5 QCalendarWidget cell and printing data inside the cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

As per requirement, I need to create a desktop application for task management. The requirement is to show all the planned activities in a calendar like format, similar to the outlook calendar. The application will also have few other push buttons for redirecting users to the respective URLs on they are clicked based on the scheduled activities on the calendar.

I'm developing this desktop application using python's PyQt5 module. I have created the required push button and for task management, I have created the calendar using QCalendarWidget. I'm also able to access the individual cells and able to print the date based on used clicks on the calendar.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMenuBar, QAction, QDialog, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QLabel, QCalendarWidget, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize


class Window(QDialog):
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                win = QWidget()
                self.title = "Calendar Application"
                self.top = 100
                self.left = 100
                self.width = 400
                self.height = 400
                self.InitWindow()

        def InitWindow(self):
                #self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("heading.png"))
                self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
                self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
                self.createMenu()
                self.createHeader()
                self.createHomeLayout()
                self.show()


        def createHeader(self):
                gboxLayout = QGridLayout()
                self.label = QLabel("Calendar Application")
                gboxLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1)
                self.header_groupBox = QGroupBox()
                self.header_groupBox.setLayout(gboxLayout)

        def createMenu(self):
                mainMenu = QMenuBar()
                fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("File")
                helpMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Help")

                exitAction = QAction('Exit', self)
                helpAction = QAction('About Us', self)

                fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
                helpMenu.addAction(helpAction)

        def createHomeLayout(self):
### --------------------------- ACTIVITY Widget --------------------------------- ###

                hbox = QHBoxLayout()
                self.activity_groupBox = QGroupBox("Activities")
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.activity_groupBox.setFont(font) 
                self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()

                self.button1 = QPushButton("Activity-1", self)
                self.button1.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button1.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)

                self.button2 = QPushButton("Activity-2", self)
                self.button2.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button2.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button2, 0, 1)

                self.button3 = QPushButton("Activity-3", self)
                self.button3.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button3.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button3, 0, 2)

                self.button4 = QPushButton("Activity-4", self)
                self.button4.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button4.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button4, 1, 0)

                self.button5 = QPushButton("Activity-5", self)
                self.button5.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button5.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button5, 1, 1)

                self.button6 = QPushButton("Activity-6", self)
                self.button6.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button6.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button6, 1, 2)

                self.button7 = QPushButton("Activity-7", self)
                self.button7.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button7.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button7, 2, 0)

                self.button8 = QPushButton("Activity-8", self)
                self.button8.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button8.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button8, 2, 1)

                self.button9 = QPushButton("Activity-9", self)
                self.button9.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button9.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button9, 2, 2)

                self.button10 = QPushButton("Activity-10", self)
                self.button10.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button10.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button10, 3, 0)

                self.button11 = QPushButton("Activity-11", self)
                self.button11.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button11.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button11, 3, 1)

                self.button12 = QPushButton("Activity-12", self)
                self.button12.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button12.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button12, 3, 2)

                self.button13 = QPushButton("Activity-13", self)
                self.button13.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button13.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button13, 4, 0)

                self.button14 = QPushButton("Activity-14", self)
                self.button14.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button14.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button14, 4, 1)

                self.button15 = QPushButton("Activity-15", self)
                self.button15.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button15.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button15, 4, 2)

                self.button16 = QPushButton("Activity-16", self)
                self.button16.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button16.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button16, 5, 0)

                self.button17 = QPushButton("Activity-17", self)
                self.button17.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button17.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button17, 5, 1)

                self.button18 = QPushButton("Activity-18", self)
                self.button18.setMinimumHeight(40)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.button18.setFont(font)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button18, 5, 2)

                self.activity_groupBox.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
                #self.report_groupBox.setLayout(gridLayout)


### ------------------------ REPORTS Widget -------------------------------- ###

                self.report_groupBox = QGroupBox("Reports")
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Verdana")
                font.setBold(True)
                self.report_groupBox.setFont(font)

                vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

                cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
                cal.setGridVisible(True)
                cal.clicked[QDate].connect(self.showDate)
                vbox.addWidget(cal)

                self.lbl = QLabel(self)
                date = cal.selectedDate()
                self.lbl.setText(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                vbox.addWidget(self.lbl)

                hbox.addWidget(self.activity_groupBox)
                hbox.addWidget(self.report_groupBox)
                self.setLayout(hbox)

        def close(self):
                self.close()

        #def recruitWindow(self):
        def showDate(self, date):
                self.lbl.setText(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

The requirement now is to access each cell of the calendar and highlight it if there is any activity schedule and also mention the activity name in the cell, similar to the outlook calendar. All the activity name and schedule will be given as input in an excel sheet. I'm able access the calendar cells but not sure how to highlight the cells and print the scheduled activity in the cell.

Is that possible? Am I on the right track or should I think of some other ways?

The QCalendar can be accessed with from this link.

[image]

Comment: Not everyone knows how the outlook calendar looks, so it is difficult to understand what you want, you could place an image and better explain what you want to obtain.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the post with the image link. I'm required to highlight the date cells which have some scheduled activities and also print those activities in these date cells. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by highlighting ?, the image you provide does not help at all, what do you mean by printing? If you want help you should be more attentive to the questions.

Comment: @eyllanesc by  highlighting I meant to say that colouring the cells in different colour, similar to the way current day in highlighted in the image.  I'm aware of the paint that is available in PyQt5 but not sure if that can be used for colouring cells as per condition.   Also I want to write the task names within these coloured cells. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `QCalendarWidget` and redefine the method `paintCell()`.

For example, to print a red dot in each cell where you have an event:

```
class Scheduler(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.events = {
            QDate(2019, 5, 24): ["Bob's birthday"],
            QDate(2019, 5, 19): ["Alice's birthday"]
        }

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.events:
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was directed to this question when I had a similar question but the answer provided didn't work, I managed to get an answer to the question to help me. I thought this might help anyone who needed help with a similar question to this.

This is the code i was given:

```
        connection = sqlite3.connect("YourDatabase.db")
        crsr = connection.cursor()
        crsr.execute("""SELECT Date FROM CalendarTable""")

        date_format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        cell_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        cell_format.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("lightblue"))

        for row in crsr.fetchall():
            date_str, *_ = row
            dt = QtCore.QDate.fromString(date_str, date_format)
            if dt.isValid():
                self.calendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(dt, cell_format)
            else:
                self.DateInfoOutput.setText("{} does not match format {}".format(date_str, date_format))
```

To use this code in your program you need to create a database like this:
[The Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKJG6.png)

This will then output like this:
[The Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biBTT.png)

I will also link my question to see the full code to make the final output.
[How to Output sql data onto a QCalendarWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645241/how-to-output-sql-data-onto-a-qcalendarwidget)